Append dynamic values to a request using script
I have a simple POST request that's testing a user sign up form. I have some basic values in the Body tab:



Key
Value




givenName
Test


familyName
Test



and then I wanted to set some dynamic values when making the request like this:
const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
const body = req.getBody();

req.setBody({
  ...body,
  username: `username${random}`,
  email: `test${random}@test.com`
});

The req.setBody usage is shown in the documentation and I was hoping to append the request of the body set in the Body tab.
Is there anyway to do this or do I need to stick to one way or the other?
